# resulting HTML from $compile(custom-directive) doesn't bind {{values}}

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, mapbox, angularjs-compile

I want to dynamically add Angular custom Directives, but the directive  resulting from $compile(directive) doesn't have the 2-ways binding.

Here's my simplified problem: I am using MapBox, and I want to use Directives for the the markers' popup to show, for example, the markers' title. MapBox wants HTML as a String to put inside the popup, so my idea was to pass a $compiled directive, something like `$compile('<myDirective></myDirective>')($scope).html()`.

It replace the directive with its template, but {{values}} are not solved.

I have something like this to create the popup

```
map.featureLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) 
 {
  var marker = e.layer;
  var popupContent =  ctrl.createPopup(marker);
  // popupContent should be HTML as String
  marker.bindPopup(popupContent);
 });
```

`ctrl.createPopup(marker)` call a function of the controller, that does:

```
this.createPopup = function(marker)
{
 var popup = "<mapbox-marker-popup"
            +"      title = "+marker.feature.properties.title
            +"</mapbox-marker-popup>";
 // should return HTML as String
 return  ($compile(popup)($scope).html());
}
```

where `mapbox-marker-popup` is a directive specified as follow:

```
 /* ===== MARKER POPUP DIRECTIVE=========== */

 .directive('mapboxMarkerPopup', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: [
                "<p>{{title}}</p>",
               ].join(""),
     scope:
        {
         title: '@'
        }
    }    
 })
```

Anyway... *mapboxMarkerPopup* is not working. *title* is shown as `{{title}}`

[UPDATE2 - {{title}} not solved]

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r466xgco/)

Comment: it would be nice to have a plunker or fiddle with your code?

Comment: ok, done! I put the link in the question

Comment: I figured out that I have to do `$compile('<mydirective></mydirective>')($scope).html()`. However, content of the directive is not bound, so it's still not working. I've updated my fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the compile angular `element` instead of returning `html` of that element. Only returning the html will never carry the angular two way binding. By using compiled object you can keep your binding working.

**Code**

```
this.createPopup = function(marker) {
    var popup = "<mapbox-marker-popup" + 
      "title = '" + marker.feature.properties.title + "'" 
      + "</mapbox-marker-popup>";
    return ($compile(popup)($scope)[0]);
};
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/r466xgco/1/)

### **Update**

**$compile**

> Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template
>   function, which can then be used to link scope and the template
>   together.

Take a look at [**this link**](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angular-compile-how-it-works-how-to-use.html) will give you more idea

Comment: great! perfect.. thank you!  I didn't get very well how $compile works.

Comment: @DeLac I'd love to explain that..but it has already explained in many places so I've added a link my answer..you can refer to it..